# Segmentation Violation when running MATLAB r2017a with caffe (python script)

Tags: python, matlab, deep-learning, caffe, ubuntu-17.10

I get the following crash when running Matlab r2017a with caffe from python script (selective_search.py from https://github.com/sergeyk/selective_search_ijcv_with_python). I run it with user root on ubuntu 17.10 and CPU mode only!. I also tried to run *.m file with matlab and it works fine. you can see below more details. also you can see below the matlab script parameters (['matlab', '-softwareopengl' atc)

```
    root@desktop-home:/home/USERNAME/deepLearning/hed/python# python detect.py /home.USERNAME/Desktop/input.txt /home/USERNAME/Desktop/output.csv

CPU mode !!!!!!
WARNING: Logging before InitGoogleLogging() is written to STDERR
I0102 22:59:10.099709  3052 net.cpp:50] Initializing net from parameters: 
name: "FCN"
input: "data"
input_dim: 1
input_dim: 3

...
...
...

I0102 22:59:10.636869  3052 upgrade_proto.cpp:620] Attempting to upgrade input file specified using deprecated V1LayerParameter: /home/USERNAME/deepLearning/hed/examples/hed/5stage-vgg.caffemodel
I0102 22:59:10.847916  3052 upgrade_proto.cpp:628] Successfully upgraded file specified using deprecated V1LayerParameter
Loading input...
selective_search_rcnn({'/home/USERNAME/Desktop/camera_500_X_500.jpg'}, '/tmp/tmphzvr5w.mat')
['matlab', '-softwareopengl', '-nojvm', '-r', "try; selective_search_rcnn({'/home/USERNAME/Desktop/camera_500_X_500.jpg'}, '/tmp/tmphzvr5w.mat'); catch; exit; end; exit"]
['matlab', '-softwareopengl', '-nojvm', '-r', "try; selective_search_rcnn({'/home/USERNAME/Desktop/camera_500_X_500.jpg'}, '/tmp/tmphzvr5w.mat'); catch; exit; end; exit"]

/home/USERNAME/deepLearning/hed/python/selective_search_ijcv_with_python

No protocol specified

------------------------------------------------------------------------
       Segmentation violation detected at Tue Jan  2 22:59:13 2018
------------------------------------------------------------------------

Configuration:

  Crash Decoding      : Disabled - No sandbox or build area path

  Crash Mode          : continue (default)

  Current Graphics Driver: Unknown software 

  Current Visual      : None

  Default Encoding    : UTF-8

  Deployed            : false

  GNU C Library       : 2.26 stable

  Host Name           : USERNAME-home

  MATLAB Architecture : glnxa64

  MATLAB Entitlement ID: 3324953

  MATLAB Root         : /usr/local/MATLAB/R2017a

  MATLAB Version      : 9.2.0.556344 (R2017a)

  OpenGL              : software

  Operating System    : Linux 4.13.0-21-generic #24-Ubuntu SMP Mon Dec 18 17:29:16 UTC 2017 x86_64

  Processor ID        : x86 Family 6 Model 158 Stepping 9, GenuineIntel

  Window System       : No active display

Fault Count: 1


Abnormal termination:
Segmentation violation

Register State (from fault):
  RAX = 00007f80b7df83d0  RBX = 0000000000000000
  RCX = 0000000000000000  RDX = 00007f80b7df8600
  RSP = 00007f80b7df82a0  RBP = 00007f80b7df8790
  RSI = 00007f80bc3b6833  RDI = 00007f80b7df8390

   R8 = 0000000000000000   R9 = 0000000000000000
  R10 = 00000000000003ad  R11 = 00007f80dbe55fe0
  R12 = 00007f80b7df8390  R13 = 00007f80b7df8600
  R14 = 00007f80b7df88a0  R15 = 00007f80dc10a7a0

  RIP = 00007f80bc37c628  EFL = 0000000000010202

   CS = 0033   FS = 0000   GS = 0000

Stack Trace (from fault):
[  0] 0x00007f80bc37c628                      bin/glnxa64/libmwddux_impl.so+00661032
[  1] 0x00007f80bc356be9                      bin/glnxa64/libmwddux_impl.so+00506857
[  2] 0x00007f80bc3466b6                      bin/glnxa64/libmwddux_impl.so+00439990
[  3] 0x00007f80bc34c85a                      bin/glnxa64/libmwddux_impl.so+00464986
[  4] 0x00007f80bc348370                      bin/glnxa64/libmwddux_impl.so+00447344
[  5] 0x00007f80d7cbe7d2                             bin/glnxa64/libmwms.so+03168210
[  6] 0x00007f80bc34808a                      bin/glnxa64/libmwddux_impl.so+00446602
[  7] 0x00007f80da64bf65 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2017a/bin/glnxa64/libboost_thread.so.1.56.0+00073573
[  8] 0x00007f80db6757fc              /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0+00030716
[  9] 0x00007f80db3a2b0f                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+01133327 clone+00000063
[ 10] 0x0000000000000000                                   <unknown-module>+00000000


If this problem is reproducible, please submit a Service Request via:
    http://www.mathworks.com/support/contact_us/

A technical support engineer might contact you with further information.

Thank you for your help.** This crash report has been saved to disk as /root/matlab_crash_dump.3072-1 **



MATLAB is exiting because of fatal error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "detect.py", line 178, in <module>
    main(sys.argv)
  File "detect.py", line 149, in main
    detections = detector.detect_selective_search(inputs)
  File "/home/USERNAME/deepLearning/hed/python/caffe/detector.py", line 120, in detect_selective_search
    cmd='selective_search_rcnn'
  File "/home/USERNAME/deepLearning/hed/python/selective_search_ijcv_with_python/selective_search.py", line 51, in get_windows
    raise Exception("Matlab script did not exit successfully!")
Exception: Matlab script did not exit successfully!
```

Comment: You run it as root? What? Why?

Comment: Please change "we" into "I".. unless you're British royalty?!

Comment: Furthermore you're output looks like bugreport and therefore was flagged for reviewing. As stated by the code: **If this problem is reproducible, please submit a Service Request via:
    http://www.mathworks.com/support/contact_us/**

Comment: @CrisLuengo because the python script should run as root.
ZF007 already submitted.

Comment: Did you try running python in a bash with a shebang, sudo could be enough in that case.

Comment: what did you mean by shebang?